Removing collection duplicates by a specific field
I wrote the code to remove the duplicate id from Employee list and print unique one with all their details.
So here I am able to remove the duplicate and printing unique, but other employee details not printing
can you please help me on this issue to print the Employee Name, salary with their unique details?
Here is my snip of code
Employee POJO
package com.demo.streams;

public class Employee {

    Integer empId;
    String name;
    Double salary;

    public Employee(Integer empId, String name, Double salary) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(Integer empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPhone() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setCity(Long phone) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Name :" + name + "  Phone :" + salary + "   Emp Id :" + empId;
    }
}

My Main Class
public class RemoveDuplicateId {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> listObj = Arrays.asList(new Employee(5, "Raju", 8967452, "Infosys"),
                new Employee(6, "Shayam", 78564589, "Tcs Ltd"), new Employee(3, "Mantu", 677890, "Wipro"),
                new Employee(5, "Shayam", 878965, "Tech-Mahindra"), new Employee(8, "Guudu", 987653, "Cisco"));
        List<Integer> id = listObj.stream().map(e -> e.geteId()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (Integer sorted : id) {
            System.out.println(sorted);
        }

    }
}

out put
5
6
3
8


Does this answer your question? Java 8 Distinct by property

Do not map to id if you need the other properties. You can for example store the Employee in a map using the id as a key, if there are duplicate ids keep the first or last seen as per your requierment and get the values of that map
List<Employee> empsDistinctById = new ArrayList<>(
        listObj.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, emp -> emp, (first, second) -> first))
               .values());

for (Employee emp : empsDistinctById) {
    System.out.println(emp);
}


You could use an external Set to filter duplicates using filter:
List<Employee> listObj = ...
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>(listObj.size());
listObj.stream().filter(e -> seen.add(e.getEmpId())).forEach(System.out::println);

Output:
Name :Raju  Phone :89674.52   Emp Id :5
Name :Shayam  Phone :785645.89   Emp Id :6
Name :Mantu  Phone :6778.9   Emp Id :3
Name :Guudu  Phone :9876.53   Emp Id :8


First, your employee class has errors.

your constructor doesn't match the invocation.

public Employee(Integer empId, String name, Double salary) {...}
new Employee(3, "Mantu", 677890, "Wipro"),


you have the following mixed up methods.

public Double getPhone() {
    return salary;
}

public void setCity(Long phone) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

And you apparently have different companies with different employees with the same user id. Which duplicate employee id do you want to ignore?
Normally, you would check an ID against a single company of employees since ID's are inherently unique within a company.  In this case, you should check for equality of the instance.  I have overridden equals and hashCode to do this. I use all fields for computing hashCode and equals.  This is not required.  The fields chosen must be make sense on how the class is to be used.
Below I made some changes to show how this might normally be done.  Instead of focusing on employee Id which doesn't make sense as you have multiple companies which could have overlapping ids, I created duplicate entries in the list.  So this will remove duplicates based on the equals implementation which is critical for this to work as stated in the JavaDoc for streams.

Stream distinct()
Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

I omitted the getters and setters as they weren't germane to this particular exercise.
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Employee {

    int empId;
    String name;
    double salary;
    String company;

    public Employee(int empId, String name, double salary, String company) {
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.company = company;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(company, empId, name, salary);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
       
        if (obj instanceof Employee other) {
            return this.hashCode() == obj.hashCode()
               && this.empId == other.empId
               && this.company.equals(other.company)
               && this.salary == other.salary
               && this.name.equals(other.name);
        }
        return false;
                        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name :" + name + "  Phone :" + salary + "   Emp Id :" + empId;
    }
}

public class RemoveDuplicateId {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> listObj = List.of(
                new Employee(5, "Raju", 8967452, "Infosys"),
                new Employee(6, "Shayam", 7856489, "Tcs Ltd"),
                new Employee(3, "Mantu", 677890, "Wipro"),
                new Employee(6, "Shayam", 7856489, "Tcs Ltd"),
                new Employee(5, "Raju", 8967452, "Infosys"),
                new Employee(8, "Guudu", 987653, "Cisco"));
        
        List<Employee> uniqueList = listObj.stream().distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (Employee sorted : uniqueList) {
            System.out.println(sorted);
        }

    }
}

prints
Name :Raju  Phone :8967452.0   Emp Id :5
Name :Shayam  Phone :7856489.0   Emp Id :6
Name :Mantu  Phone :677890.0   Emp Id :3
Name :Guudu  Phone :987653.0   Emp Id :8

